# Cannot install Python module 'arcgis'

Tags: python, pip, arcgis

I try to install the module arcgis from the cheese shop and it fails. Here the cli...

```
(base) PS C:\Python311\Scripts> .\pip3.11.exe install arcgis
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Python311\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C:\Python311\Scripts\Lib'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Python311'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Python311\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Python311\\Scripts'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Python311'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Python311\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Python311\\Scripts\\Lib',
    'C:\\Python311\\DLLs',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Looking for solutions people either point at PYTHONHOME or PYTHONPATH, neither of them are set and this is also no virtual environment. The Python version I use is 3.11 and the module description is pointing at Python >=3.9, <3.12.

Any suggestion what the real problem is and how to over com it?

Comment: Possible issue as noted here: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/99004  (dunno if it's fully applicable to your issue)

Comment: Hmm, seems independent of the module then, and according to the date of the last comment it is still an issue.

Answer (score -1):

just type from conda command prompt : pip3 install arcgis

output :
Collecting arcgis
Downloading arcgis-2.2.0.2.tar.gz (48.0 MB)
---------------------------------------- 48.0/48.0 MB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... -

Comment: Would be nice if that's possible, but I need to get 'arcgis' into FME, most likely leaving me with pip: https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Form/Workbench/Installing-Python-Packages.htm

And yes, we also have ArcGIS Data Interop. but the functionality we are after is not provided by the existing transformers in that version of FME.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).